# Notify the front end of changes on the back end

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I have an app with a back end running Express.js and the front end on React.js.

In the app the user uploads a file on the front end to the back end, the back end then processes it and when it's done it sends the processed file to the front end.

I would like to notify the front end of the changes that are occurring on the back end as the file is been processed.

My question is: Should I use socket.io to do this?. There could be two or more users using the app for different data at the same time, can I notify each user of each process separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I use socket.io to do this?

Yes.  That is a good application for socket.io.

> There could be two or more users using the app for different data at the same time, can I notify each user of each process separately?

Yes, each socket.io connection can be sent messages separately.